# dependency injenction insert to database operation with unity and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to integrate dependency injection by employing unity container in an ASP.NET MVC app. In the spirit of loose coupling, I apply constructor injection on my controller and my product data access class. This is a glimpse of the code :

```cs
public interface IProduct
{
   IEnumerable<Product> findAll();
   Product find(Guid id);
   void create();
}
public class Product()
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    //dependency
    private IDBEngine _engine = null;

    public Product(IDBEngine engine) {
        this._engine = engine;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> findAll() {
        using(IDBconnection connection = this._engine.getConnection()) 
        {
            connection.open();

            //implementation of fetching all datas from db

            return datas;
        }
    }

    public Product find(Guid id) {
        using(IDBconnection connection = this._engine.getConnection()) 
        {
            connection.open();

            //implementation of fetching single data given id from db

            return data;
        }
    }

    public void create(Product product) 
    {
        using(IDBconnection connection = this._engine.getConnection()) 
        {
            connection.open();

            //implementation of insert data to db
        }
    }
}
```

well this is my implementation on my controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    private readonly IProduct _product;

    public HomeController(IProduct product)
    {
        this._product = product;
    }

    public ActionResult index() {

        //this is OK
        var products = this._product.findAll();

        //this is also OK
        var product = this._product.find(Guid.Parse("some_guid"));

        //this is not OK, cause it made the controller depend on concrete class Product
        this._product.create(new Product {
            id = Guid.newGuid(),
            name = "Vader Shirt",
            price = 99.5
        });

        return View();
    }
}
```

I inject the Product instance to the controller via `container` with unity. When I call the `findAll()` and `find()` method, it was totally fine cause it still let me decouple the controller and the concrete class `Product` using the IProduct interface. But when I had to do insert operation via `create(Product product)` method, I had to create an instance of product to do so, hence coupled my controller to a concrete class : Product.

My question is how do I decoupled my controller and at the same time perform the create method from my controller? And I think it goes the same for the update operation.

Comment: The methods should be a service - e.g. `ProductService` implements `IProductService`, not methods of the `Product` class

Comment: could you give examples? how is it different from my implementation?

Comment: And you not _decoupling the controller and the concrete class_ `var products = this._product.findAll();` is `IEnumerable<Product>` and `var product = this._product.find(Guid.Parse("some_guid"));` is `Product`

Comment: it's not Product, it's interface of Product IProduct .. could you please give examples in the answer?

Comment: It is `Product` Your controller and your views need models not interfaces (you cannot even bind to an interface!). And your interface even has `IEnumerable<Product> findAll();`! Rename `interface IProduct` to `interface IProductSerice` and create `class ProductService : IProductService` and then move the 3 methods from `class Product` to class ProductService`

Comment: Yes, passing model to the view from the controller is irrelevant in this question, cause it's just a mock controller..but how changing interface and class names could fix my problem?

Comment: It not irrelevant! Your controllers and view need models not interfaces, You cannot 'decouple' them. What you do decouple is the service that is responsible for getting and saving instances of your models.

Comment: Yes yes, I understand that I need to pass model to view like return View(products) but my question is not about passing model to a view.. But how can I do insert operation without coupling my controller with the concrete class.. If I can't please do tell me..

Comment: You cant. But your model should not contains those methods. They belong in a service (how can a class `Product` which describes a single `Product` return a collection of `Product`?), You inject `IProductService` into your controller, and in you `ActionResult Create(Product model)` method, you call `_ProductService.Create(model);`

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Muecke gave a good advice there, try this:

```
public interface IProductService{
   void CreateProduct(Guid id, string name, double price);
   IEnumerable<Product> FindAll();
   IProduct Find(Guid id);
  }
```

then your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public HomeController(IProductService service)
    {
        this._productService = service;
    }

 public ActionResult index() {

        //this is OK
        var products = this._productService.FindAll();

        //this is also OK
        var product = this._productService.Find(Guid.Parse("some_guid"));

        this._productService.CreateProduct(
            id = Guid.newGuid(),
            name = "Vader Shirt",
            price = 99.5
        );

        return this.View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I go with createProduct(Product product) instead of your suggestion? So I still have to create instance of concrete class product in my controller to do the insert operation?

Comment: @caesardo yes you can pass in a `Product` instance. The point of this answer is that you should separate data from behaviour. `Product` is data and can be `new`d up as business logic defines, `ProductService` is behaviour and should be injected into the controller.